# How to specify which version of perl to use on CentOS

Tags: linux, perl, version, centos5

I am running CentOS 5.4 which only has version 5.8 of perl available by default, and I have a program which requires perl 5.10, so I compiled perl 5.10 on CentOS.  How do I specify which perl I want to run the program with because the perl command uses 5.8 by default.

Comment: Beware of clobbering your vendor/distro-supplied Perl with a newer version-- sometimes system tools are written for the version they came with and you can cause dependency issues.

Answer (score 14):

I add my voice to recommending against messing with the system perl at all.

No one mentioned [App::perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew) yet. It allows you to have several versions of Perl and switch between them easily. This can be done manually of course but it's much easier to have this tool to do it for you; from the Pod–

```
# Install some Perls
perlbrew install perl-5.12.2
perlbrew install perl-5.8.1
perlbrew install perl-5.13.6

# See what were installed
perlbrew list

# Switch perl in the $PATH
perlbrew switch perl-5.12.2
perl -v

# Switch to another version
perlbrew switch perl-5.8.1
perl -v

# Switch to a certain perl executable not managed by perlbrew.
perlbrew switch /usr/bin/perl

# Or turn it off completely. Useful when you messed up too deep.
perlbrew off

# Use 'switch' command to turn it back on.
perlbrew switch perl-5.12.2
```

Comment: Using perlbrew to hook into 5.10 is not going to work well with Apache, especially if you are using mod_perl.    You can get an Apache-launched script to run through perlbrew but it is not very efficient.    The most efficient method will be via mod_perl hooks, but then perlbrew is not going to help.    Doing a parallel install of 5.10 will be better, and update Apache/mod_perl to use the 5.10 install v. the system 5.8.

Answer (score 6):

The first line of the program file should reference the perl binary you wish to use:
e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

You may also want to change your PATH variable so that the directory your perl 5.10 binary is in is listed prior to the 5.8 binary directory.
e.g.

```
export PATH=/path/to/perl/5.10:$PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to make symbolic links to my different perl executables in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ [sudo] ln -s /path/to/perl5.10.1.exe /usr/local/bin/perl510
$ [sudo] ln -s /path/to/perl5.13.8.exe /usr/local/bin/perl513
$ ... etc. ...
$ # and just for completeness
$ ln -s /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/bin/perl58
```

and then just invoke:

```
$ perl510 script_to_use_with_v5.10.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called alternatives that was designed to deal effectively with exactly this kind of problem. It basically gives you an easy way of switching between different version of applications by manipulating symbolic links in e.g. your bin directories.

Say "man alternatives" in a terminal (or yum install alternatives, if you don't have it installed).

Answer (score 0):

set your PATH environment variable to point to your new perl executable. For instance

```
 export PATH=/newpath/perl:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, The perlbrew package is available for installation from the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository for CentOS 5.x. I tried to install just this rpm initially but it has a number of dependencies so I opted to add the EPEL repository to my list of yum repos on my box.

Answer (score 0):

solution has two parts ... first edit myscript.pl which wants specific version

```
old
#!/usr/bin/perl

new
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

above has no impact on normal executions of the script ... when you want  above myscript.pl to use a specific perl version create a wrapper script which contains

```
export PATH=/cool/new/version/perl:$PATH
#  now execute script on following line
/path/to/myscript.pl
```

this way other invocations of the script remain unchanged and they just use default perl whereas launcher wrapper script executes same myscript.pl script with chosen perl version