# perlbrew perl cpanm faulty

Tags: perl, perlbrew, cpanm

I installed a module under cpanm, apparently incorrectly. It is visible and usable when running under system perl, but not under perlbrew. However, perlbrews cpanm is stating that module has been successfully installed. Best steps to take?

```
/Users/john/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/bin/perl
/Users/john/perl5/bin/cpanm
#!/usr/bin/perl
MM: INSTALL_BASE=/Users/john/perl5
MB: --install_base "/Users/john/perl5"

Note: .pl file contains following
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

After perlbrew switch...

```
declare -x PERL5LIB="/Users/john/perl5/lib/perl5"
declare -x PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION="0.76"
declare -x PERLBREW_HOME="/Users/john/.perlbrew"
declare -x PERLBREW_MANPATH="/Users/john/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/man"
declare -x PERLBREW_PATH="/Users/john/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/john/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/bin"
declare -x PERLBREW_PERL="perl-5.18.2"
declare -x PERLBREW_ROOT="/Users/john/perl5/perlbrew"
declare -x PERLBREW_VERSION="0.76"
declare -x PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/Users/john/perl5"
declare -x PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/Users/john/perl5\""
declare -x PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/john/perl5"
```

[Link to sybase install with hombrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660109/installing-dbdsybase-on-os-x-with-homebrew-fails-to-find-freetds-libraries)

Comment: Please provide the output of `which perl ; which cpanm ; head -n 1 "$( which cpanm )" ; printf 'MM: %s\n' "$PERL_MM_OPT" ; printf 'MB: %s\n' "$PERL_MB_OPT"`

Comment: In perlbrew try the following. `$ cpanm --interactive -v App::cpanoutdated`,  `$ cpan-outdated`, `$ cpanm --interactive -v App::CPAN::Fresh`. Then do `cpanm <module::name>`.

Comment: Check to see that the permissions are correct on the just installed files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cpanm` doesn't install any modules. It just runs the installer packaged with the distributions you want to install. Via the `PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT` env vars, you are instructing those installers to install the modules in the wrong location. Get rid of them.

Comment: but wont the installs change location depending on which cpanm is used. I performed suggestion. Using perl under perlbrew,  Can't locate DBD/Sybase.pm. Using system perl, all is fine. /Users/john/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/Sybase.pm. Want to make certain cpanm next install is for perlbrew copy

Comment: PERL5LIB="/Users/john/perl5/lib/perl5" This is the problem. How could I move files from here to   ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/lib/5.18.2/

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. Not sure how I got to this point.

Comment: Re "*but wont the installs change location depending on which cpanm is used*", By default, the `perl` used will determine where the module is installed, but you are overriding this.

Comment: Re "*How could I move files from here to ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/lib/5.18.2/*" DON'T MOVE THEM. Just install the modules using the Perl for which you want them to be available.

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and could not understand how to make `cpanm` install modules for the intended Perl.  I had installed `perlbrew` via:

```
perlbrew --switch --notest install perl-stable
```

I thought that `--switch` would direct my usage to the new Perl, and I could see the new Perl was there via:

```
perlbrew exec perl -v | grep 'This is'
```

But installing modules with `cpanm` was not working (the modules wouldn't be found) when I would run my scripts via:

```
perlbrew exec perl myscript.pl
```

This [which-version-of-perl post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764025/how-to-specify-which-version-of-perl-to-use-on-centos) made me consider that maybe `--switch` had not had the effect I'd wanted.  Running the following allowed `cpanm` to start installing to the intended Perl:

```
perlbrew switch perl-5.26.1
```